# Mysql sample of 2 elements with the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

There is an internet shop, goes to the basket of goods by sample ID, and it is necessary that some of the goods in the basket were in the amount of not more than 2, and thus in one basket can be a number of goods from one ID.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM goods 
 WHERE id IN (101842,101842,101838,101840)
```

However, only in the sample cell 3 as can generate a request to the sample were all four elements?

How can I get 4 elements in this sql query?

Comment: You may need to post some sample data with expected result

Answer (score 0):

If you add an second condition for id you will have the second id. I had the same problem i resolved by this way. Be sure by looking in with mysqlbrowser if you have only one or more.